# Autocompletion in Vim (highlighting the first match)

Tags: vim, autocomplete, mapping

I'm trying to use [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE) mapping but there is a problem.

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <C-n> pumvisible() ? '<C-n>' :
\ '<C-n><C-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>Down>" : ""<CR>'
```

In my case it does highlight the first match when I press `<C-n>` but If I continue typing to narrow the matches, highlighting doesn't work anymore.
I'm using vim 7.4 and I've also tried running with `--noplugin` to prevent any conflicts but no luck.

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug. Patch 7.4.018 https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/z7t9rxSHnkk/p5H0doyIQAsJ

Comment: I installed the latest version and now it works, thanks